# choosing the right networking and web service technology in .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, networking

[This document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645029%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) is really great at helping to choose the right networking and web service technology in Silverlight. Where is a similar document for .NET (4.0)? I suppose there are some other options an things to consider when not constrainted by Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Options to consider for .NET are the same.  The APIs will have usually some more flexibility but the overall role of each option is the same.